# Meteor createContainer and Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, meteor, redux

I created a Meteor `createContainer` to wrap the entire App to just look for `Meteor.users()`:

```
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import { createContainer } from 'meteor/react-meteor-data';

import App from './../App.js';

export default AccountContainer = createContainer(() => {
  const _id = Meteor.userId();
  const accountHandle = Meteor.subscribe('userData', _id);
  const loading = !accountHandle.ready();
  const user = Meteor.users.findOne(_id);
  const userExist = !loading && !!user;

  return {
    loading,
    userExist,
    user
  };
}, App);
```

I need to use this data all around the App to show / hide elements and to take control of User private pages like a control panel.

I'm using Redux to store the data coming from `createContainer` and actually I'm doing it in the `App.js` file:

```
// a few imports here...

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    const { loading, userExist, user } = this.props;
    this.props.updateUser({ loading, userExist, user });

    return (
      <Router history={history}>
        <div className="app">
          <Header />
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
            <Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />
            <Route exact path="/signup" component={Signup} />
            <Route exact path="/account" component={Account} />
            <Route exact path="/account/pictures" component={Pictures} />
          </Switch>
          <Newsletter />
          <Footer />
        </div>
      </Router>
    );
  }
};

export default connect(null, { updateUser })(App);
```

As you can see here I call `this.props.updateUser({ loading, userExist, user });` and it update my redux store.

The issue is that I do receive the following error:

> Warning: setState(...): Cannot update during an existing state
>   transition (such as within `render` or another component's
>   constructor). Render methods should be a pure function of props and
>   state; constructor side-effects are an anti-pattern, but can be moved
>   to `componentWillMount`.

This because I'm updating Redux state within the `render()` App method.

I tried wrapping it between a `setTimeout`:

```
setTimeout(() => {
  this.props.updateUser({ loading, userExist, user });
});
```

This solve my issue but I think it is not the best solution to fix it.

I'm confused about how and when to update Redux state using Meteor `createContainer`.

What I wish to achieve is to be able share the `{ loading, userExist, user }` data all around the App taking that information using for ie in `Account.js`:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return state.user;
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Account);
```

Thanks.

**EDIT**:
Just moved the Redux update frm `render()` to `componentDidMount()` method.
It doesn't show the error anymore, it update well in `App.js` but in `Account.js` I don't get it updated, it looks like it miss it:

[image]

Comment: Why do you want to do this inside your render method? Why not do this in the componentDidMount lifecycle to update your state?

Comment: If I move it in `componentDidMount` I don't see it changed in other Components...

Comment: I see the user updated in `App.js` but it doesn't update in `Account.js`. using the code you see at the bottom of my question... I don't know where is my error...

Comment: I see. Isn't your store your single source of truth? I'm sorry, I'm not familiair with Meteor. Maybe your container doesn't exist yet in app. You should use redux logger middleware to see what's exactly going on inside your reducers. Also, you can try to use the componentDidUpdate lifecycle, and set the state based on a condition to prevent going in an infinite loop. That's all I can think of!

Comment: I just updated the question, please have a look at what happen. Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Confusion with Meteor createContainer and React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45658787/confusion-with-meteor-createcontainer-and-react)

Comment: @Styx I did that previous question and this is a more detailed question that that one... Read before doing these actions. Thanks.

Comment: @AyeyeBrazo you have the same issue here, perhaps it would be better to update your previous question instead of creating new?

Comment: @Styx, no. That question was related to a totally different thing. Once updated my code following a user comment I have found a different issue not related at all with that question: previous question was related to how share Meteor data along the whole app (Redux as a possible solution). This question is dedicated to Meteor and Redux. When can we Redux dispatch  accordingly with Meteor `createContainer`? 2 very different arguments.

Comment: @FabianTjoeAOn Regarding users yes. I do need to keep reactivity using Meteor `createContainer` because `componentDidMount` doesn't work as expected using Meteor. So the workaround is to use it and the dispatch to Redux. The point is when and where to dispatch.

Comment: @AyeyeBrazo, I'm not familiar with Redux, but coudn't you pass the user object from `App` to `Accounts` via props, using `render` instead of `component` inside your `Route`? Something like 
`<Route exact path="/account" render={<Account user={user} />} />`. Let me know it this works!

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't re-render and props is always undefined. Thanks for the hint btw...